# All employees under supervisor - ms access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have been looking for solutions to a basic problem for a while and I have no idea where to start. First thing is the problem:

I have a table that contains all the staff, in there is a field for the staff members direct supervisor. I after selecting a supervisor at the top and get all the staff that they directly control or control through others.

So for example I will use this table:

```
StaffID  |  SupID  |  Name
1        |   Null  |  A
2        |   1     |  B    
3        |   1     |  C
4        |   2     |  D
5        |   3     |  E
6        |   5     |  F
```

I want so that the selection of StaffID: 1 Gives all staff but the selection of 3 gives only 3, 5, and 6

I have found plenty of ways to do this with SQL-server but this project is in Access and limited to that program.

Comment: access sql doesn't support recursion. you'd need to a self-join for every layer of ancestry. e.g. if you have ceo->vp->division head -> boss -> peon, you'd have to self-join 4 times to get all levels of supervision. that or query in a loop, once for every possible layer, building in the supervisors list as you go.

Comment: Am I looking/missing something? If 1 is selected, you would have Staff 2, 3 and if 3 is selected only 5 should be returned. Should it not (based on your sample)? How come 1 will give everyone? How come 3 will give 3, 5 and 6?

Comment: @PaulFrancis - "that they directly control or *control through others.*"

Comment: @MarcB is right.  One way to do it is to join the table to itself multiple times.  You will need to look at aliasing and joins.  Or if you are doing this in code, you could create a recursive function that reads the employee's underlings and then calls itself with each of those underling's id's.

Comment: @Gilchrist - thanks also for the help.